# Single datanode is storing more data in Hadoop 5-node cluster

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I have 5 node HDP cluster of version 3.1.1.In that 2 Name nodes and 3 data nodes. I am maintaining default replication factor 3. But MAX data is storing in the first data node only. see below disks utilization.

```
MASTER 1:

/dev/sdd1        63G   71M   60G   1% /opt/disk02
/dev/sdc1        63G   71M   60G   1% /opt/disk01

MASTER 2:
/dev/sdd1        63G  121M   60G   1% /opt/disk02
/dev/sdc1        63G  121M   60G   1% /opt/disk01

SLAVE 1:
/dev/sdd1        63G  4.0G   56G   7% /opt/disk02
/dev/sdc1       126G   14G  107G  12% /opt/disk01

SLAVE 2:
/dev/sdd1        63G  5.0G   55G   9% /opt/disk02
/dev/sdc1       126G  5.5G  114G   5% /opt/disk01

SLAVE 3:
/dev/sdc1       126G  5.0G  115G   5% /opt/disk01
/dev/sdd1        63G  4.0G   56G   7% /opt/disk02
```

How do I replicate the data equally in all data nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You can't control exactly in what data nodes the replications will be placed, but in your case it should be on every node.

Maybe using concepts like https://www.waytoeasylearn.com/2018/01/rack-awareness-in-hadoop-hdfs.html racks and using Cloudera or Hortonworks.

Also try balancing your data http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2755708&seqNum=5 as the issue may be solved.

Even if your general replication factor is 3, maybe for a path, it is 1 or 2, better check that also [HDFS can I specify replication factor per file to increase avaliability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111653/hdfs-can-i-specify-replication-factor-per-file-to-increase-avaliability)

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop automatically controls where the data and replication needs to be placed as already mentioned by Horatiu.
But it is possible that sometime data may get skewed across some or single node.

HDFS might not always place data in a uniform way across the disks due to following reasons:

1. A lot of writes and deletes
2. Disk replacement

There are few things you need to check.

1. Is there any or other files placed with manual replication factor [Control Replication factor for specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111653/hdfs-can-i-specify-replication-factor-per-file-to-increase-avaliability)
2. Is data node 1 is storing unnecessary logs
3. Try running disk balancer

To enable disk balancer dfs.disk.balancer.enabled must be set true in hdfs-site.xml.

Please refer [HDFS disk balancer](https://data-flair.training/blogs/hadoop-hdfs-disk-balancer/)